# Difference between form1.controls.add() and page.controls.add() in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Many times i have seen this code

```
Form1.controls.add()
```

and sometimes it is

```
Page.Controls.add()
```

What is the difference and when should they be used.

I am asking in context of a normal asp.net page without any master page. Content pages doesnot have Form1.controls.add().

Comment: You should normally neither add controls to the page nore to the form directly, instead add them to Container-Controls(PlaceHolder,Panel,Div,etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Any asp.net web-control will give you a method to add controls inside since html is a nested markup language. In this particular case, Page contains Form1 control.

If you call,

```
Forms.controls.Add()
```

The control hierarchy  after adding the control would be..

```
Page --> Form1 --> YourNewlAddedControl.
```

If you call,

```
Page.controls.Add()
```

The control hierarchy  after adding the control would be..

```
Page --> Form1
Page --> YourNewlAddedControl.
```

Comment: Sir, is there any particular scenario where i should prefer one over other.According to my understanding everything should be inside form tag in a asp.net page.so when a control is placed outside form tag,does it behave differently.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it to make sure.  Adding a Literal to the Page worked fine, but adding a TextBox to the Page gave me a yellow screen of death with this error: "Control 'txt1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."  So certain controls need to be inside the Form.

Comment: So when i dynamically load usercontrol, i use page.controls.add(usecontrol1) and it places it outside form tag.so it should not work but it works.how???

Comment: Any `input` control must be placed inside a form. Wherein a lable and other non-input controls can be placed outside the Form.

Answer (score 0):

Form is child control of Page

`Form1.controls.add()` added control like this

```
<Page>
   <Form>
       <MyControl/>
   </Form>
</Page>
```

`Page.Controls.add()` added control like this

```
<Page>
   <Form/>
   <MyControl/>
</Page>
```